# Django ORM: queryset with SIMPLE 'group by'

Tags: django, group-by, orm

I'm trying to make this simple 'group by' expression using django ORM, but I'm not sure how it would be:

```
SELECT id, title, hotel_id, booking_id, day_number
FROM `bookings_booking_item`
where hotel_id IS NOT NULL AND booking_id=xxx
group by booking_id, hotel_id

ORDER BY id asc
```

What I want to achieve is to get only one (the first) 'item' result per booking and hotel.

This is an overview of how my models look like:

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u'Name', max_length=40)
    ...

class Booking(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(u'Reference', max_length=50)
    ...

class BookingItem(models.Model):
    booking = models.ForeignKey(Booking, related_name='items', related_query_name='item')
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name='items', related_query_name='item')
    ...
```

Can anyone please help me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice if you add your models too

Comment: What database system do you use?

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem, i'm using MySQL, so 'distinct' method with fields doesn't work here :(

Comment: You are absolutely right @JPG, just updated my question attaching the models. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: apart from that, did this sql query work for you?

Comment: Yes, the raw sql works. But since i'm extending the 'get_queryset' method I can't use it as RAW, since I need to make sure it inherits other filterings.

Comment: I don't understand the query. Which title, id, day_number would be shown in the rows you fetch if the query is grouped by booking and hotel? Can you show the result of your query?

Comment: Yes, that's the result for the raw query. id, title and day_number are fields from the 'bookingitem' table. thank you!

`id title hotel_id booking_id day_number`
`810 Arrive to San José 756 845 1`
`813 Atenas to Alajuela 757 845 3`
`817 Alajuela to San José 1373 845 5`